# Can we give the zakah money to needy non Muslim?

Tags: non-muslim, zakat

Can we give the zakah money to needy non Muslim? because Allah says in Quran :
Indeed, [prescribed] charitable offerings are only [to be given] to the poor and the indigent, and to those who work on [administering] it, and to those whose hearts are to be reconciled, and to [free] those in bondage, and to the debt-ridden, and for the cause of God, and to the wayfarer. [This is] an obligation from God. And God is all-knowing, all-wise. – Al-Tawbah, 9:60

Here in this verse, it doesn't mention that the poor should be a Muslim.

Comment: In this verse it doesn't mention that the poor should be a Muslim,so please clear it.

Comment: Laws are not based on taking a single verse in isolation. The people mentioned in this verse are understood to mean Muslims because that has been narrated from the sahaba and has been accepted by the Muslims and because of other evidence that is mentioned in the linked duplicate. This verse also does not for example exclude Banu Hashim or your own children and parents etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer.